# My website Images not indexed by Google, Yahoo and Bing

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

I'm using `codeigniter` framework. why Search Engine's not indexed my website images ?
My website has been made since 2013.
My website is : `www.shadyab.com`. 
It likes groupon website(Offering daily deals at restaurants, retailers and service providers.).

An image url :

http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/kaktoos4.jpg

What should I do to tell search engines to index my website images?

My `robots.txt` is wrong ?

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin.php
Disallow: /ads/
Disallow: /patil/
Disallow: /captcha/
Disallow: /assests/
Disallow: /old_system/
Disallow: /application/
Disallow: /system/
Disallow: /baseController/
Disallow: /offer/buy/
```

Comment: Without seeing your robots.txt we cannotknow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  SEO questions belong on [webmasters.se]

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard: www.shadyab.com/robots.txt

Comment: @S.M_Emamian you did specify `Disallow: /assests/`, so...

Comment: i like `robots.txt ` files they let me know where all the stuff you want to hide is

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens I did not know there was such a place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your robots.txt file is wrong.

You have `Disallow: /assests/`[sic] and your images are in that folder...

Search engines that obey this file, will not index things in the assets folder because you asked them not to.

The fix is to remove that line from your robots.txt file and wait.